# Get the :make argument from a compiler script

Tags: vim

The `:make` command takes an argument and appends it to `makeprg`. How can I get this argument from my compiler script, which defines `makeprg`?

I have a Vim compiler script for a .NET language, and I want to define either `DEBUG` or `TRACE` depending on whether the user calls `:make` with the `-debug` argument.

Comment: Isn't it something that should be handled by the external program itself?

Comment: @romainl, sometimes one may want to produce debug symbols for a release assembly. The compiler leaves this up to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:make` injects its argument in place of `$*` in `makeprg`. To do what you want to achieve, you'll either have to write your own `:Make` that'll interpret your parameters , or have your equivalent of a Makefile recognize the `-debug` parameter and act upon it.

In my usual C++ workflow, I either choose the compilation through the `$CXXFLAGS` environment variable, or in real projects, I have one compilation directory per mode (debug, release, release with debug info, sanitize, ...), and depending on the current mode I adapt my `&makeprg` to change the `cd` done before calling make.

You may not have one compilation directory per mode, but you may be able to change the current setting of `makeprg` based on another variable.